# AngularJS prevent modal open on Enter key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I have one problem with modal window.

I have couple section and in one section ( which is hidden ) I have button with ng-click='function()'.

```
<section class='hidden'>
  <button class="mobileUpdate" ng-click="openMobileUpdateModal()">SMS</button>
</section>
```

openMobileUpdateModal() open modal dialog.
Problem is when I hit enter key on any input field in form it opens me modal window.

Any idea how to prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular bootstrap modal opening on the enter click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859779/angular-bootstrap-modal-opening-on-the-enter-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting **[the docs on `form`/`ngForm`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action)**:

> You can use one of the following two ways to specify what javascript method should be called when a form is submitted:
>
> - ngSubmit directive on the form element
> - ngClick directive on the first button or input field of type submit (input[type=submit])
>
> [...]
>   ...the following form submission rules in the HTML specification:
>
> - If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field triggers form submit (ngSubmit)
> - if a form has 2+ input fields and no buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter doesn't trigger submit
> - if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields will trigger the click handler on the first button or input[type=submit] (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (ngSubmit)

<sub>So, depending on the rest of your setup, you could solve the problem by changing the order of buttons, by detecting and filtering key-events, by introducing additional `form` elements etc.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for this, your comment helped me. Solved problem changing button to div...

Answer (score 1):

Please add **button type** to the model dialog button .

```
 <section class='hidden'>
  <button class="mobileUpdate" type="button" ng-click="openMobileUpdateModal()">SMS</button>
</section>
```

In form if we have any button enter click on input field will trigger the click event of the button.
**So always add *type="button"* to all the buttons in the form other than submit Button**

```
<form>

 Name  <input type="text"/>

 <button type="button">open model</button>

 <button type="submit">Submit Form </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859779/angular-bootstrap-modal-opening-on-the-enter-click?rq=3

Answer (score 0):

in your openMobileUpdateModal() function place the if condition to detect the key event.
if the pressed key value is 13(enter key) return from the function else continue the function.